# When uploading php files to server it deletes spaces so php is not working

Tags: php, ftp

I'am actually developing a new wordpress theme and using it on a few websites each one on the same server but  in different cPanel accounts.
The problem occurs when I download all the files on my PC and then upload them back on the server.
Let's try to be clearer, when I download a php file to my pc it looks like this:

```
<?php 
  // This is my file
  $foo = 4;
//Another comment
$foofighter = 5;
?>
```

But when I upload it to my server the code will become like this:

```
<?php // This is my file$foo = 4;//Another comment$foofighter = 5;;?>
```

That, obviusly will not work!

This is my server configuration: CENTOS 5.9 i686 standard – interserver  WHM 11.36.0 (build 14)

I use Filezilla to upload files and Notepad++ to modify and upload them when I write new code.

If I Zip the template and let WordPress upload and install it I have no problem so I think that the problem occurs when uploading single file.

A fast fix could be writing the code like this:

```
<?php 
  /* This is my file */
  $foo = 4;
/* Another comment */
$foofighter = 5;
?>
```

So 'minification' will not break my code but it's really difficult to do because i have tens of files.

Have you got any Hint?

Comment: Make sure your FTP client is transferring files in *binary* mode.

Comment: Changed filezilla default Settings to Binary Mode and now it works...
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is really simple as suggested by [@Dcoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233508/dcoder)
change your FTP client settings to *binary mode* and you are done.